# Background image in modern 2014 Q2 onwards browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the background image of a CSS button. Here's the CSS I am using:

```
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
```

Can someone tell me if I am using the very latest browsers do I still need all of these vendor specifics. One thing I noticed but maybe I am wrong. Just using the last of these in the latest Chrome browswer does not seem to work. Does that mean my specification is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need the vendor specific tags.

You can see support for browsers here:
http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Secondly, set the background property, not the background-image.

Lastly, the direction on your linear-gradient property should be changed to 'to bottom' to match the css 3 standard. More info can be found here in the browser support section: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Ex

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffffff,#d9d9d9);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzbfzd1L/

Comment: Can you suggest the format I should use to complete your answer. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer with that info.